# Using big matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, large-data, bigdata

I want to use some big matrix that can't fit in RAM memory.My matrix is not sparse.
I need this for some batch\chunk processing or online machine learning algorithms.

What I need:
1.Read some chunk of data(that can fit in RAM) from big matrix stored on hard drive and preferably I want to access it like ordinary matlab matrix.
2.Append some chunk of data to end of the big matrix stored on disc.

Comment: Before resorting to working with chunks, have you tried to use a more "economic" data type than the default `double`?

Comment: how much data are we talking about?

Comment: Amount of data doesn't matter I need "interface" to deal with big matrix, for example for my application I want to limit the size of chunk to 32Mb\1Gb\or whatever even if my computer have 8Gb of memory, so I need a method to access part of data stored on hard disk. But anyway if you interested data is about from tens to hundreds Gb.

Answer (score 3):

You will find an answer [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/10/14/new-mat-file-functionality-in-r2011b/) on reading/writing part of a `.mat` matrix.

```
%read
matObj = matfile('myBigData.mat');
loadedData = matObj.X(1:4,1:4);

%write
matObj.X(81:100,81:100) = magic(20);
```

**EDIT**

Here is some code showing the append function

```
A = ones(10,10);
save('A.mat', 'A','-v7.3');
clear A

matObj = matfile('A.mat','Writable',true);
matObj.A(8:10,8:10) = ones(3,3) * 3;       %modify
matObj.A(11,:) = ones(1,10)*4;             %append

disp(matObj.A)
```

The full matlab help for `.mat` (including limitations) is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html).

Comment: It seems that using this approach I cannot append to existing matrix, but I need to create new variable, so it will work but I must to store data in chinks?

Comment: You can append some data to the matrix. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent project on Matlab Central File Exchange that addresses the problem of large number of data points (or large matrices). 
It's Project Waterloo File and Matrix Utilities by Malcolm Lidierth

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12250-project-waterloo-file-and-matrix-utilities

Answer (score 1):

@geek_girl

Thanks for those comments. The code for the File and Matrix Utilities is on SourceForge:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/waterloo/files/Waterloo%20MATLAB%20File%20and%20Matrix%20Utilities/

A Git repo for the whole project is at:

https://sourceforge.net/p/waterloo/beta/ci/master/tree/